Related to double integration
In my research work, I got the following expression:
$\int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{Z_{lim}} 1-\exp(-\lambda*\frac{(\gamma_{th}([A+\beta^2y^2](P_u/jj1)+1/jj1)-\beta^2yz(\alpha_u-\gamma_{th}\alpha_t))}{\alpha_u-\gamma_{th}\alpha_t})*\lambda*\exp(-\lambda \cdot y)*\lambda*\exp(-\lambda \cdot z) dz dy $ --- (1)
where z and y are integration variable and all other are constants, $Z_{lim} = \frac{\gamma_{th}([A+\beta^2y^2](P_u/jj1)+1/jj1)}{\beta^2y(\alpha_u-\gamma_{th}\alpha_t)}$
After solving inner inetgration of eq.(1), I obtained the following equation:
$\int_0^{\infty} [1-\exp(-\lambda \cdot Z_{lim})-\frac{\lambda*\exp(-C_1)}{C_2-\lambda}*(\exp({C_2-\lambda}\cdot Z_{lim})-1)])*\lambda*\exp(-\lambda\cdot y) dy$ --- (2)
where $C_1 = \lambda *\frac{\gamma_{th}*([A+\beta^2y^2](P_u/jj1)+1/jj1)}{(\alpha_u-\gamma_{th}\alpha_t)}$, $C_2 = \lambda\cdot\beta^2\cdot y$
My query is that when I implemented these two equations in MATLAB then i am not getting same values for both equation (1) and (2).
So is there any mistake in derivation of eq (2).
Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Any help or clue will allow me to explore more about solving this....
